# How to plot the percentage of variable scores in several models

Tags: r

I'm a green hand in R.Now I have three data frames here：model1、model2、model3.In each data frame, there are three variables and their corresponding scores. Now I want to draw a stacked bar chart，The ordinate is three variables: A1、A2、A3. The abscissa is the name of the three data frames：model1、model2、model3. The bar filling in the graph fills the color from light to dark according to the proportion of each variable score. Here are my three data frames. What can I do to get the bar chart I want?

```
c1 <- c("A1","A2","A3")
c2 <- c(2,5,1)
c3 <- c(3,4,1)
c4 <- c(6,8,2)
model1<-data.frame(c1,c2)
colnames(model1)<-c("variable","score")
model2<-data.frame(c1,c3)
colnames(model2)<-c("variable","score")
model3<-data.frame(c1,c4)
colnames(model3)<-c("variable","score")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot to do here. First, you'd need to combine your three dataframes into one, adding some unique identifier:

```
model1$model <- "model 1"
model2$model <- "model 2"
model3$model <- "model 3"

big_model <- rbind(model1, model2, model3)
```

If you have much more than three "model" dataframes you would want to create a function that does that job for you. Then you can make the plot using ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(big_model, aes(x = model, y = score, fill = variable)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]
To understand how this all works is a bit to explain here, but [this resource](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-visualisation.html) will walk you through it nicely, and show you how to make your graph prettier.

Answer (score 0):

This one is nearly the same as [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66344885/2884859) answer.  However, if you have a large number of models, use package `gdata` to combine these models, without explicitly creating a column with data name each time

```
library(gdata)  
combine(model1, model2, model3)

  variable score source
1       A1     2 model1
2       A2     5 model1
3       A3     1 model1
4       A1     3 model2
5       A2     4 model2
6       A3     1 model2
7       A1     6 model3
8       A2     8 model3
9       A3     2 model3
```

Thereafter you can easily create a stacked bar plot in ggplot2 as

```
combine(model1, model2, model3) %>% ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(x = source, y = score, color = variable), fill = 'grey', position = "dodge")
```

[image]